# Is there a way to pass C# objects to SQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql

Some background to the problem:

I have a hierarchy of objects that looks like this: [image: ER diagram of the database]

Each 'CallAction' will have Queue OR a Question based on the 'ActionType'.
When a workflow is created through the website it is limited to 2 levels of questions. All of this has been implemented in C# and the tables created in the SQL Server. I now need to find a way to add this all to the database.

As I am extending Website Panel (an open source project) I'm trying to follow the same standards they have been using this means every call to the database is done using stored procedures.

My question is: is there any way I can just pass a 'workflow' to the SQL stored procedure and handle the multiple different levels in SQL, or am I going to have to create multiple stored procedures and handle the different levels in my C# code calling different stored procedures based on the hierarchy?

I also understand that I could access the database directly using `SQLCommand` or `LinQ` but I would rather use stored procedures if that is possible.

Comment: Although it is not the cleanest way, you can- if desired work with XML. SQL server has first citizen XML support. Serialize in .NET and pass as a parameter to your stored proc where in turn you can deserialize it.

Answer (score 3):

No such thing as objects in SQL Server. You could pass properties as named parameters to a stored proc (this way no need to maintain their order), and have the stored proc put them where they need to go: update, insert, delete.

For entire workflows, you should use matrix parameters. Google "directed network matrix representation". A single matrix will then represent all of your objects and their directed links to each other (1 - forward, -1 - back). If you want to get a little fancier, instead of using numbers, you can create a string matric which stores object names along with direction. If you multiply direction by a Real number, you get connection weight (e.g. probabilities).

But ALL this is a very backwards way of doing it. You should create this kind of adaptors in C#, and do bulk inserts/updates.

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful. Good luck.

**EDIT:** since your "workflow" looks a lot more like an ontology than a real workflow, you can see about SPARQL and such - ontology-specific SQL languages. Or Google "storing ontologies in SQL databases"

Comment: Thanks. That's given me a lot to look into.

Answer (score 2):

If you can express the hierarchy in XML, then you could pass it as an XML data type to your stored proc. The proc could then read the XML using XPath etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think **CLR Stored Procedures** can help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx

Comment: CLR procs are C# that you run from SQL, and thus don't fit parameters of this querstion. You cannot pass C# objects in them, only SQL data.

Comment: @GregoryKlopper You could serialize the object, pass it as varchar, and deserialize to the appropriate type within the procedure.

Comment: +1 True! But again, the direction is SQL to CLR, and I believe the requester is asking C# into SQL. I think by now s/he has plenty to read through and to choose the most suitable option. :-) Why I love this site.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a full C# object in as a SQL parameter, however a work-around you can try is to convert the C# object(s) into a JSON string and then work with that in the SQL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16